# Does Watir work under ruby 1.9.1?

Tags: ruby, winapi, watir

Here is the .rb program:

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new
```

the 2nd line will trigger a ""The program can't start because **msvcrt-ruby18.dll** 
**is missing** from your computer!" error.

I am using 1.9.1p378 on win32

```
ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-mingw32]
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that one of the win32 gems that Watir is using hasn't been updated to 1.9.1. We've fixed all the 1.9.1 issues we're aware of with the core Watir code.

Bret

Answer (score 2):

I had to patch Ruby 1.9.1 with these two gems:

```
win32-api-1.4.0-x86-mswin32-60.gem
win32-open3-0.2.9-x86-mswin32-60.gem
```

Try doing a Google search for either of those gems and you should find a link.  I'd host them myself but I can't access my ftp from here.